# kafka truststore file not found

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create and use a local kafka keystore.

I have created a trust store at repository_name/kafka/truststore.jks

I have config

```
props["ssl.truststore.location"] = "classpath:kafka/truststore.jks"
props["ssl.truststore.password"] = "password"
```

but when i boot up the app I get the kafka error

`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: classpath:kafka/truststore.jks at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)...`

This is a problem with the pathing I have used as I tried the absolute path and got no error. This however is not a solution as it is a shared repo, the path must be from the repo not absolute. I did try some alternate pathing such as `kafka/truststore.jks` which did not work.

The command used to create the keystore was

`keytool -keystore truststore.jks -genkey -alias ts`

Comment: Last I checked, `classpath:` is not a valid JVM file URI. I've only seen this used in Spring-specific use cases. So, you get the same error with an absolute path?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have just tried using the absolute path and it worked, thanks! This proves it is a problem with the pathing. Sadly this is a shared repo so it needs to be pathed from the repo not absolute. 
Do you know what the JVM way of getting the jar path would be? It needs to be in the string as when this code is running on the server it is using a different keystore that is not in the jar and the local keystore path will get overwritten.

Comment: There probably is a way to get the JVM "working directory" of the application, but why cant you just pass in a CLI parameter of the needed paths when the JAR is executed?